# Has checkmate ever been achieved by castling kingside in a high-level game?

Tags: history, checkmate, castling, famous-games, master-games

Has checkmate ever been achieved by castling kingside in a high-level game?

I asked an AI large language model, but it listed games which certainly didn't achieve checkmate with castling kingside. I also tried searching the web but didn't come across any.

Comment: ChatGPT is great at acting like it knows the answer, not so much at actually answering. Morphy did it once in an odds game: https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1238144

Comment: @David great find. A beautiful game

Comment: ChatGPT is great at acting like it knows the answer, even when answering pure bullshit. Anderssen didn't castle at all in the Immortal Game - and neither did Kieseritzky. Morphy castled *queenside* against Brunswick & Isouard.

Comment: This sounds like something a simple [tag:cql] query could solve, right? I don't have a proper database to run it on...

Comment: I am only aware of a (blitz) game (White was Eduard Lasker , a brother of world champion Emanuel Lasker) where White mated by castling queenside , but not with the king side as desired.

Comment: I don't think the ChatGPT part adds anything to the question, but it's customary to require some evidence of trying to figure out the answer oneself, so I don't know what to do with it...

Comment: @JiK Good point. I removed it (it's still accessible via question edit history for anyone interested in what ChatGPT thought).

Comment: Emmanual Lasker did have a brother, but he was called Berthold. I think Edward was a distant cousin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to that [CQL](http://gadycosteff.com/cql) query :

```
cql(input Megabase2023.pgn)

mate
move previous from [Kk] o-o
```

There are [twelve games](https://gist.github.com/signed-log/f1f3d221dfe1353ac70bae31441b2614) where the castling king side delivered a checkmate, 4 of which played by 1600+ players

---

```
[Title "Wiedermann, Daniel (2048) v. Wagner, Leopold Franziskus (2168) - Blitz Playchess.com (2020)"]
[FEN ""]

1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 e6 3.Nc3 Bb4 4.f3 Bxc3+ 5.bxc3 O-O 6.e4 d5
7.cxd5 exd5 8.e5 Nfd7 9.f4 c5 10.Nf3 Nc6 11.Bd3 c4 12.Bxh7+ Kxh7 13.Ng5+ Kg6
14.f5+ Kxf5 15.Qh5 Nf6 16.O-O#
```

```
[TITLE "Kreyssig, Bruno (1828) v. Heilmann, Karl Ludwig (1665) - Forchheim 12th 2013"]
[FEN ""]

1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 Nf6 5.Nc3 g6 6.Be3 Bg7
7.Be2 O-O 8.f4 Nc6 9.Nb3 Be6 10.g4 Na5 11.g5 Ne8 12.h4 Bc4 13.h5 Bxe2 14.Qxe2
Qc7 15.Nd5 Qd8 16.hxg6 hxg6 17.Qh2 f6 18.f5 fxg5 19.Qh7+ Kf7 20.fxg6+ Ke6 21.
Qh3+ Ke5 22.Bd4+ Kxe4 23.Nc3+ Kf4 24.O-O#
```

---

```
[TITLE "Moreno, Jose Enrique (1622) v. Pereira, Gerardo (1400) - Montevideo Duchamp Cup 1st 2017"]
[FEN ""]

1.e4 Nc6 2.d4 d5 3.e5 e6 4.Nf3 Be7 5.c4 b6 6.Nc3 Ba6 7.
cxd5 Bxf1 8.dxc6 Ba6 9.a3 h6 10.Be3 f6 11.b4 fxe5 12.Nxe5 Bf6 13.Qh5+ Ke7 14.
Ng6+ Kd6 15.b5 Qe8 16.Bf4+ e5 17.dxe5+ Kc5 18.Be3+ Kc4 19.Qe2+ Kxc3 20.Rc1+ Kb3
21.Qc4+ Kxa3 22.Rc3+ Kb2 23.Qb3+ Ka1 24.O-O#
```

---

```
[Title "Naqopia, Giorgi (1680) v. Nurijanyan, Alex (1610) - Poti op 14th 2019"]
[FEN ""]

1.e4 c5 2.b4 cxb4 3.a3 d5 4.exd5 Qxd5 5.Bb2 Nf6 6.axb4 Bg4 7.Ne2 Nc6 8.Nbc3 Qd7 9.h3 Bh5 10.Qb1 e5 11.b5 Nb4 12.Ba3 a5 13.bxa6 Rxa6
14.Ng3 Rb6 15.Bxb4 Bxb4 16.Ra8+ Ke7 17.Rxh8 Bxc3 18.Nf5+ Qxf5 19.Qxb6 Qe4+ 20.
Qe3 Qb4 21.f3 Nd5 22.Qg5+ f6 23.Qxg7+ Ke6 24.Qg8+ Kf5 25.Bd3+ Kf4 26.g3+ Kxf3
27.O-O#
```